# WSO2 Storage Server integration

Tags: api, wso2, integration

WSO2 community.

Exists some predefined API (as WEB-SERVICES ?) or Java API (carbon maybe) to integrate this. (Need some basic facilities as create/delete user/tenant/database, get existent databases etc.) or should I start to develop this web-services in SS?
TY!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these soap services.

[RSSAdmin](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-storage-management/blob/master/components/rss-manager/org.wso2.carbon.rssmanager.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/rssmanager/core/service/RSSAdmin.java) - to provision databases

[RemoteUserStoreManagerService](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs) - for user management

[TenantManagementService](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Tenant+Management+with+APIs) - for tenant management